# Chi-Square test for independence for field failure data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test

I'm analyzing the product field failure data where each product can have one or more failures (Failure A, Failure B, Failure C, Failure D etc.) My goal is to understand the correlation between failure A and failure B. The challenge is the sample of the failure data I have is biased i.e. for example if 10000 products are sold, 100 samples have failures rest work fine.

1. Does analyzing only samples with failure will lead to incorrect results? Does it violate any assumption of the chi-square test?
2. Is the below contingency table correct? Then should "Not Failure A, Not Failure B" cell  have "0" (n4) as frequency? or should all the failures (failure C and D as well) be taken into account in the contingency table?

|  | Failure A | Not Failure A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Failure B | n1 | n2 |
| Not Failure B | n3 | n4 |

3. I think Failure A and B are related based on nature of the failure. Is the null hypothesis (Failure A and Failure B are independent) still valid? (I remember reading in somewhere, null hypothesis is something ordinary happens and alternative is something extraordinary happens - in case of the data I have having correlation seems to be ordinary scenario.

Comment: Chances are you mean "Not Failure A" in the second entry in the first row of the table?

Comment: You write that "the sample is biased", but the plain fact that there are many products without failure is not a "bias". If indeed failure happens rarely, this should be reflected in your sample, in which case there is no bias. Or are you saying that there is also some kind of bias in your sampling and the sample doesn't reflect correctly what is going on (i.e., not a representative/random sample)?

Comment: @ChristianHennig Indeed, it should have been "Not Failure A". Corrected now. Thanks!

Comment: The product which are working fine are not returned. So the analyzed sample only consists of the products failed in the field. That's what I mean by bias.

Comment: Ah OK. Indeed then the sample is biased, however does it make sense to assume that the other projects all have no failures? Because in this case you could well count them into your sample and it would be unbiased (if I understand the situation correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand your situation correctly and there is no sampling bias (see my comment, I assume you use the word "bias" incorrectly, but of course I may be wrong).

In this case:

1. All samples should be used in your analysis. If you only use the samples with failure, this will induce negative dependence between failure A and failure B, because if you know that (i) there is no failure A and (ii) there is a failure, this makes it more likely that there is failure B (because there must be some failure). So you need to consider a situation in which you do not assume (by only using data with failure) that there is a failure.
2. Consequently, n4 should include all cases in which there is no failure (plus of course those in which there is a failure different from A or B).
3. You can think that A and B are related and have a null hypothesis that they are independent. You then think that the null hypothesis is not true, and if you reject it, this actually gives evidence in favour of your belief. The null hypothesis may not be true, but it is still valid as a null hypothesis to be tested. (If it's crystal clear to everyone that A and B are related, it may not be very informative to reject the null hypothesis that they are not, though.)